# How to solve inequalities with both $\log$ and $e$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just realized (better late than never) that I have a problem with certain inequalities. For example, let

$$ x^4 \log x + 3 e^{\frac{1}{x^2}} \geq 0 .$$

Beyond finding the domain, if I start to move around with $\log$, I don't go anywhere and it looks like changing the variable does not help either. Basically, I don't know how to tackle something like this.

How to solve such an inequality?

Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to solve inequalities that involve a mix of polynomials, logarithms and exponents, just like there is no way to solve such *equalities*.

In your case, however, it is possible to prove that the inequality is true on $(0,\infty)$ by showing that the expression on the left has only one local extreme and that the extreme is a minimum (and the expression is positive at that minimum).

Comment: I see (problem of being self-thaught): nice to know I should not be that ashamed of myself, and - yeah - I had the feeling it was the same with the equality issue. So, either we go with derivatives or we don't go anywhere: good to know. May I ask you some reference that explains why such expressions have no *simple* solution?

Comment: @Kolmin I wouldn't say "go derivative or go home", I'd rather leave it at "it depends on the problem, although derivatives work sometimes". In general, what you are asking is when an equation has an **analytic closed form** solution, so I'd start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Analytic_expression

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback!